# Redirecting errors from rmdir /S /Q to NULL device doesn't work

Tags: windows, makefile, mingw, rmdir

I wrote very simple `Makefile` to show problem which I got. Please take a look:

Makefile:

```
.PHONY: clean

clean:
    -rmdir /S /Q not_existing_directory >nul 2>&1
```

Running this `Makefile` with command `make clean` doesn't redirects errors from `rmdir` to the `NULL` device. The interesting thing is that running the same command from `cmd.exe` works as expected, namely it hides errors. My question is why is it happening ?

This error manifested on Windows 7 32-bit version as `make` I'm using `mingw` from http://www.mingw.org/ in following version:

```
GNU Make 3.82.90
Built for i686-pc-mingw32
```

Here are also my enviromental variables which I'm setting through batch file:

setenv.bat:

```
set PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Program Files\COSMIC\CXSTM8;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\Vim

%comspec% /k PATH
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain any more why this is working, but I had the same problem and I'm using the following to really quiet commands in Makefiles with `cmd`:

```
>nul 2>nul & verify >nul
```

To keep the Makefile compatible with `sh`, too, it might be a good idea to define variables, I use for example this in an include for `cmd`:

```
CMDSEP := &
PSEP := \\
CPF := copy /y
RMF := del /f /q
RMFR := -rd /s /q
MDP := -md
CMDQUIET := >nul 2>nul & verify >nul
```

while the following section is for `bash` and other `sh`-compatible shells:

```
CMDSEP := ;
PSEP := /
CPF := cp -f
RMF := rm -f
RMFR := rm -fr
MDP := mkdir -p
CMDQUIET := >/dev/null 2>&1
```

example usage:

```
distclean: clean
    $(RMF) conf.mk
    $(RMFR) $(SDKDIR) $(CMDQUIET)
    $(RMFR) $(OUTDIR) $(CMDQUIET)
```

Comment: this is actually working. Thanks a lot for this. I use variables in my makefile as well. I just wanted to show the SSCCE to get fine answer as yours. Maybe some will also know why is it happenning.

Comment: Indeed, an explanation should be there, I just can't remember it ... we will see!

Comment: Do you have any idea how to queit only some kind of errors ? like that one that directory doesn't exist. But let the user of the makefile know that he/she wanted to perform clean but it wasn't successful because some other program used the files so they cannot be deleted.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I'm pretty sure this is a hard limitation of `rd` (as opposed to the nice `rm -fr` on linux) ...

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but in batch you would say something like `if exist not_existing_directory rd /s /q not_existing_directory`.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I was thinking about this, too, and it's probably the best one can do here. Just keep in mind there is a theoretical race condition (testing and removing is not "atomic" like it would be with `rm -fr`), but that's probably not of practical relevance.